# Animation - smooth movement

Tags: animation

I know this has been asked many times, but cannot find an answer. I recently changed my interpola from Bezier to Linear, then back again. I might have accidentally changed the handles too. Now, everything animated before then change move smoothly, but all animation I added later is at position A, then instantaneously snaps to B. How can I fix this so it actually moves?

Comment: If I understand you correctly either add a new key frame or replace existing one(s).

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: The thing is that if you even change interpolation to Linear and then back to Bezier there won't be any reasons to make animation jump from one keyframe to another. Probably the interpolation was changed to Constant. Could you show screenshot of Graph Editor with exact that object which animation began to jump ?

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to constant, but I changed it back to Bezier...

Comment: For some reason I can't upload pics... but it's just a straight line then drops at the animation point. (BTW I only  changed the z location.)

Comment: For some reason I redid the animations today and now it works, but thanks for the suggestions!